# Шаблоны страниц в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-webforms

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть база данных, в ней таблицы:
 1. City 
 2. Role
 3. Otdel
 4. Department
для этих таблиц есть страницы, чтобы создавать/редактировать данные. Внешне эти страницы идентичны, но наполнение и таблицы(из которых берутся данные) для каждой страницы разные. Так вот, вопрос в следующем: можно ли сделать одну такую страницу, которая бы меняла содержимое для соответствующей таблицы, что-то типа шаблона страницы с динамическим наполнением. Полностью динамическая страница, я думаю, будет слишком долго работать. Может кто сталкивался с подобным вопросом, подтолкните в нужную сторону.
Использую ASP.NET 2(WebForms), но можно решения и для версий выше.
Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы ищите [Master Pages][1].


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp

Comment: @Shad Эм, не совсем, если я правильно понял, то Master Pages - это тот контент, который должен отображаться на каждой странице, типа header, footer, menu. Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Да, смотрите в сторону мастер-страниц. Это некий общий макет, в которой динамически будет рендерится содержание других страниц.

Comment: @drovka, не совсем. Master page - это шаблон, в котором определена "общая" разметка для набора страниц. В нем есть элемент(ы) `ContentPlaceHolder`, которые будут заполняться динамически, в зависимости от конкретной страницы.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться с Master Page дальше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набросал небольшой примерчик по вашему вопросу, с использованием **master pages**.

Во-первых, необходимо создать шаблон для ваших похожих страниц. Он будет содержать в себе общую разметку и элемент(ы) `ContentPlaceHolder`. Например (пускай файл называется Table.Master):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <header> ... </header>
        <section>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="TableContent" />
        </section>
        <footer> ... </footer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Теперь можно создавать страницы для каждой из 4-ёх таблиц, используя этот шаблон. Например:

```
<%@ Page Title="Roles" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Table.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="RoleTable" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="TableContent">
    <h2>таблица Role</h2>
    <table>
        <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody> ... </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

или

```
<%@ Page Title="Cities" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Table.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="CityTable" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="TableContent">
    <h2>таблица City</h2>
    <table>
        <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody> ... </tbody>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Важно отметить два момента:

- В директиве `<% Page %>` нужно указать имя файла шаблона - `MasterPageFile`
- Нужно определить блок `<asp:Content>`, задать ему такой `ContentPlaceHolderID`, какой указан в шаблоне как `ID` для элемента `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` и всю разметку поместить внутрь этого блока.

В итоге, при запросе за отдельной страницей, вся разметка, находящаяся внутри блока `<asp:Content>` будет обработана и подставлена в шаблон на место элемента `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`.

Полную информаицю по данной теме можно получить на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX)'е (однако она на английском языке).

---

- В шаблоне можно использовать более одного элемента `ContentPlaceHolder` и соответственно заполнять их на "дочерних" страницах
- У страницы-шаблона в свою очередь тоже может быть задан шаблон. То есть можно сделать что-то наподобие иерархии шаблонов.

Comment: О, супер, то, что нужно! Огромное спасибо за помощь.